# Maven: How to manage test code module dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, codenameone

We've migrated an ant project (codename one) to a maven project which happened through a migration tool. Unfortunately there is still a problem. Somehow, the test source directory (set via `testSourceDirectory` in pom.xml) becomes part of the wrong module (it is at least shown so in the project view of IntelliJ IDEA). Therefore the test source code is missing neccessary core dependencies. The core code (actual implementation) is in the "common" module. Even though the test code is located (in IntelliJ) under the "common" module, it is itself marked as being part of the "cn1libs" module. We have no idea, how the ide or maven concludes this from the pom config.

snippet from the pom:

```
<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/common/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

[image: test root in wrong module somehow]

the dependencies in the test sources can't get resolved

[image: test sources problem]

How can we fix this?

Comment: Setting such things via `<testSourceDirectory>`... is simply wrong... make an example project on Github or alike...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes IntelliJ will give you erroneous labels like this if there is more than one module that references that directory in their pom file.  Check your cn1libs/pom.xml file and make sure that it doesn't have `<testSourceDirectory>` specified anywhere.  Its packaging type should also be `pom`.

Codename One projects are set up to do unit tests using the Codename One test runner.  It uses its own "test" goal.  You are importing junit's `Test` class which may be problematic here unless you really know what you are doing.  E.g. The Codename One testrunner will set up the test environment and run the tests in a simulated environment.  Junit will just run them raw.

If you need to add test dependencies, however, you should be able to just add them in the *dependencies* section of the common/pom.xml file, just make sure you set the dependency scope to "test".

Comment: actually right before we've read your answer we noticed that the erroneous labeling is really a intellij thing since in a template project taken from https://start.codenameone.com/ the same thing happens, but that project runs without any problems. And also, in compliance with your dependency suggestion, we managed to add those dependencies via intellij's conext menus. I was going to post this progress here but noticed you've already pointed it out righlty, thanks

Comment: the only thing still causing trouble is the following (we hopefully will fix on our own):

[ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.xyz:app-CN1CircleProgress:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.xyz:app-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.xyz:app-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> org.xyz:app-CN1CircleProgress:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> org.xyz:app-common:1.0-SNAPSHOT @